# Unity3D: Метод бросания луча

Tags: unity3d

Читаю книгу "Unity в действии" Джозефа Хокинга. Сейчас я на главе 3, где мы пишем шутер от первого лица. Мне не понято как реализован метод бросания луча(для реализации выстрелов, и еще пара моментов). Смотрите комментарии в коде. Прошу объяснить мне, заранее спасибо!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RaySh : MonoBehaviour {

    private Camera camera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        int size = 12; 
        float posX = camera.pixelWidth / 2 - size / 4; //зачем здесь вычитается size / 4
        float posY = camera.pixelHeight / 2 - size / 2; //зачем здесь вычитается size / 2
        GUI.contentColor = Color.black;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(posX, posY, size, size), "*");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){ // полностью не понятен метод бросания луча (код ниже)
            Vector3 point = new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth / 2, camera.pixelHeight / 2, 0);
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(point);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                StartCoroutine(SphereIndicator(hit.point));
            }
        }

    }
    private IEnumerator SphereIndicator(Vector3 pos){   
            GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            sphere.transform.position = pos;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            Destroy(sphere);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Происходящие внутри void OnGUI(){} - это отрисовка элемента интерфейса на экране. Является устаревшим API и в будущих выпусках может быть выпилен в связи с моральным устареванием.

Size там вычитается из-за особенностей конструктора [Rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html). Он принимает не центр и ширину с высотой, а верхний левый угол и ширину с высотой. В итоге, чтобы картинка оказалась по центру экрана - нужно отнять половину ширины картинки от половины ширины экрана и прибавить половину высоты картинки к половине высоты экрана.

Почему автор отнимает оба показателя и почему ширину делит на 4 - мне не понятно. Видимо, он хочет поместить изображение ниже центра и чуть правее о.о

Дальше поясняю сам бросок луча. Комментарий ниже строчки кода.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

Если нажата ЛКМ

```
 Vector3 point = new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth / 2, camera.pixelHeight / 2, 0);
```

Здесь создаём вектор равный центру экрана в пиксельных каординатах (т.е. ширину и высоту камеры в пикселях делим пополам). В Unity такой вектор считается ScreenPoint, т.е. позиция чего-либо в пиксельных координатах экрана, а не мира.

```
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(point);
```

С помощью специального метода камеры создаём луч, который будет запускаться из камеры в ScreenPoint точку. Метод так и называется, как видите - `ScreenPointToRay`. В нашем случае мы пускаем луч в высчитанный центр экрана. Условно - это луч, начало у которого - координаты камеры и выпущен он будет в центр экрана.

```
RaycastHit hit;
```

Переменная, которая содержит информацию о столкновении луча с каким-либо коллайдером.

```
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
```

Использование метода физики, который бросает луч по заданным настройкам и возвращает bool - столкнулся ли луч с каким-то объектом. Если столкновение произошло, то в переменную hit будет передана информация об этом столкновении. У самого метода есть много перегрузок, чтобы можно было бросать лучи из точки в точку, использовать маски слоёв и много другого.

```
StartCoroutine(SphereIndicator(hit.point));
```

Запуск какой-то корутины. Судя по именованию и сигнатуре, в точке столкновения с коллайдером `(hit.point)` на какое-то время появляется сфера.